# mark, del, ins tag cooperation

Tags: html

I have noticed same behavior which for me seems to be strange, maybe it is correct behavior, please let me know. I have noticed that "mark" tag does not work in same matter when is used with "del" and "ins" tags.

Example:
`<mark><b>Lorem ipsum </mark> amet.</b> Phasellus`
Marked and bold part is "Lorem ipsum ", and "amet" is only bold as expected.

`<mark><i>Phasellus e,</mark> at pellentesque enim.</i>`
Marked and italian part is "Phasellus e,", and only italian is " at pellentesque enim." - I think it is fine.

`<mark><u>Suspendisse quis mi</mark> volutpat.</u>`
Marked and underline part is "Suspendisse quis mi", and only underline is " volutpat." - I think it is fine.

`<mark><del>sagittis elit ut</mark> nisi suscipit,</del>`
Marked and del part is "sagittis elit ut", but part "  nisi suscipit," become without any formation. Isn't it suppose to work in a same manner as tags above?

`<del>sagittis <mark>elit ut</mark> nisi suscipit,</del>`
Using mark tag inside del seems to be working as expected. "sagittis " is only underlined, "elit ut" is underlined and marked, "nisi suscipit" is only underlined.

Same behavior is for tag "ins" (same as "del"). So my question is if this representation is correct for the tags "del" and "ins", because it seems like not.

Comment: None of your examples except the last one are correct HTML to begin with, so not sure what you are actually asking here. Is it, _“is there a chance that the automatic error correction applied by the browser will lead to unwanted results if I mess up my HTML in the first place?”_ Then the answer is yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks for  the comment but Alohci already explained me what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, or as correct as can be expected, given that the HTML in each case is invalid.

Some elements are considered *[formatting elements](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#formatting)* . These are `a`, `b`, `big`, `code`, `em`, `font`, `i`, `nobr`, `s`, `small`, `strike`, `strong`, `tt`, and `u`. (Note that some of these are obsolete elements).

When tags are closed out of order, these elements, if currently open, are closed and [then reopened](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#reconstruct-the-active-formatting-elements), giving you the behaviour you see for `b`, `i` and `u`. But `ins` and `del` are, like `span` not formatting elements and are just closed and not reopened, so you get the behaviour you see for `del`.